# What else can stop me from accessing my WIndows 7 etc/hosts file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hosts-file

Microsoft have recently rolled out a ridiculous change to Windows Defender which "detects" the deliberate blocking (via the `hosts` file) of Microsoft and other telemetry domains as an "attack", even though the destination IP is 0.0.0.0.

Having, as I thought, told Defender to accept this "serious threat", I am now completely unable to edit, or even read, my `hosts` file. I have tried all the advice given in previous, similar, questions, to no avail. Namely:

- Taken ownership of the file
- Set my permissions on the file to "Full Control"
- Tried editing in an elevated instance of NotePad++ ("Cannot read file")
- Tried copying to desktop for editing there (Unable to copy - "Access denied")

Can anyone with better knowledge than mine help? What mechanism is keeping me from seeing my own files? And, more important, how do I get round it?

(Windows 7 Home Premium)

Comment: Try from a different user name (make a new one if need be). HOSTS is normal on my Windows 7 VM and on my Windows 10 Host machine. What did you do, changes to HOSTS you may have made?

Comment: One of the things this is showing you is that using the HOSTS file isn't how to accomplish this task anymore.  I used to use it too to block ad sites.  The thing is only there for legacy purposes (and a few sideways hacks).  IMHO, you should use your firewall to block things, not the hosts file.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas There actually two reasons I want to modify `hosts`. One is to block telemetry; the other is to set up a set of  private domain names for my LAN. Sideways hacks? Yes, but ten times more productive than tinkering with a firewall I don't understand.

Comment: @John Thanks for the idea. But I'm afraid it didn't work.